# How to create a tensor by accessing specific values at given indices of a 2 X 2 tensor in pytorch?

Tags: pytorch, tensor

Suppose
`mat = torch.rand((5,7))` and I want to get values from 1st dimension (here, 7) by passing the indices, say `idxs=[0,4,2,3,6]`. The way I am able to do it now is by doing `mat[[0,1,2,3,4],idxs]`. I expected `mat[:,idxs]` to work, but it didn't. Is the first option the only way or is there a better way?

Answer (score 2):

[`torch.gather`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.gather.html#torch.gather) is what you are looking for:

```py
torch.gather(mat, 1, torch.tensor(idxs)[:, None])
```